# Hiding x Axis in dojox.charting

Tags: dojox.charting

How can I hide the x Axis when create a chart using dojox.charting.chart2D?

Answer (score 1):

simply, you can delete the code to the axis x:

```
chart1.addAxis("x", {
            natural : true,
            includeZero : true
        });
```