# Question about label in axis

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

How can I remove the labels and keep the Y axis?

I don't want remove the axis, only the labels. Basically the y axis without text or numbers

[image]

```
chart1.addAxis("y", {
                labels: false,
                vertical : true,
                leftBottom : true,

            });
```

Comment: You're much more likely to get answers if you post the code you're using to create this chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try like this:

```
addAxis("y", {
                vertical: true,
                fixLower: "major",
                fixUpper: "major",
        labelFunc:function(){
          return " ";
             }
         });
```

Pls. Dont remove the one single space inside the quotes.

or here is a post which shows how to delete an axis from the chart.
[Hiding x Axis in dojox.charting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568887/hiding-x-axis-in-dojox-charting)